# Losing image on resize browser or rotate screen

Tags: html, css

I've got a background image that stretches across my page inside a `div`. The image has a transparent block over the top.

When I resize the browser or rotate the page on a mobile device, part of the image disappears.

[image]

```
#home-area 
{
    background: url("../images/home-bg.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.overlay 
{
    background: rgba(43, 191, 217, 0.30);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I also have a `position: fixed` menu at the top of the page.

Any ideas why the image isn't resizing when the screen resizes?

Comment: could you give us your HTML layout as well? A JSFiddle would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Setting up some simple markup:

```
<div id="home-area">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
</div>
```

With your classes, the re-sizing seems to work well (though some of the image begins to get cut off as `background-size: cover;` retains the image aspect ratio) in Chrome and IE11 on Win7, no white block like you seem to be mentioning in the picture. It looks like you are on a Win8 machine perhaps in IE?

Though when I emulate a different resolution in IE there is some pretty erratic behavior when scrolling around.

Perhaps this will help more [Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)